# retryAnalyzer : "NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()" is thrown even new session has been re-created

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I am using TestNG version 6.9.10 and Selenium 3.8.1 with Java 1.8

I use retryAnalyzer to keep restart my @Test if exception is thrown during the @Test. 
Everytime exception is thrown somewhere in the middle of my @Test

1. I catch it
2. Write it to the log files
3. Call `driver.quit()`
4. And then re-throw it
5. RetryAnalyzer will then stop the remaining codes and restart from the very beginning of my `@Test`
6. At the beginning of my `@Test` , I always check whether the browser is still open. If yes, just go the URL I want to test. If not, open a new Chrome driver and go to the test URL.
7. At this step, a new Chrome browser will get started and the test URL will be displayed.
8. But after that, I will not be able to execute the test (e.g. executing `driver.findElements()` ) , it will throw me exception `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?`   even though I have recreated a new driver session (after destroying it).

After destroying the driver session by using driver.quit() , can we recreate a new driver session by `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`  ?  or it is not the right way to recreate a new driver session?

Here is my codes:

```java
public class myTest {

  private WebDriver driver;

  //This codes in BeforeTest below will initiate a new chrome driver session 
  @BeforeTest
  public void initiate() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverpathchrome);
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("www.test.com");
    log.info("Chrome browser launched. Going to " + "www.test.com");
  }


  private boolean isBrowserOpen() {
    try {
      driver.getTitle();
      return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public boolean amISeeingLoginScreenNow() {
    if (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".login-box.smaller")).size() != 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  //This is the test methods
  @Test(retryAnalyzer = myTest.RetryAnalyzer.class)
  private void loginToTestURL() throws Exception {

    //This will check if the current browser session is still open. If not, then create a new driver session
    if (this.isBrowserOpen() == false) {
      Thread.sleep(3000);

      // Initiating new Browser 
      this.initiate();
    } else {
      driver.get("www.test.com");
    }


    this.method_will_not_throw_exception() {
      //some codes that will work OK
    }


    try {
      this.method_will_throw_exception() {
        //some codes that will throw exception
        this.amISeeingLoginScreenNow(); //In the 2nd try , at this stage, Selenium will get grumpy
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      //put exception in the log files then re-throw the exception
      //retryAnalyzer will get the exception and then start the test from the start of @Test
      driver.quit();
      throw new AssertionError();
    }

  }
}
```

When exception is thrown, retryAnalyzer will start from @Test . I always re-create a new driver session by calling the `this.initiate();`  After that, a new browser session is started and go to test URL. So far so good.

But when executing further codes such as `driver.findElements()` Selenium complains and give me

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
System info: host: 'DEV2015003', ip: '10.0.1.164', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:131) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:398) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:469) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElements(By.java:441) ~[selenium-api-3.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:359) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.8.1.jar:?]
    at myTest.myMainTest.amISeeingLoginScreenNow(SSDSearchPage.java:4219) ~[bin/:?]
```

I wonder why Selenium complains that Session ID is null. I have recreated a new session at the very beginning of my `@Test`. A new browser session appears and go to my test URL. That means a new driver session has been created successfully. But when executing `driver.findElements()` Selenium gets upset. 
Any suggestions or pointers maybe?

If I didn't call driver.quit();  it will be OK. No problem. 
But I want to restart the browser and get a new session everytime retryAnalyzer retries the test. 
Thank You very much.

Comment: are you sure you actually re-initialized your driver? eg you went into that first 'if' statement? I can't tell what's actually throwing the exception since it's out of `amISeeingLoginScreenNow` which isn't in your sample code.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the sample codes. The `amISeeingLoginScreenNow` is basically executing `driver.findElements(); `

Comment: Use driver.close() instead of driver.quit().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got the solution.

Apparently, after I destroy the driver using either `driver.close()` or `driver.quit()` , I must re-initialised the driver right away **before** throwing exception to `retryAnalyzer`.

When `retryAnalyzer` gets the exception and retry the `@Test` , the driver session must have been re-initialised , fresh Chrome browser session must have been started and ready to use.

If I re-initialise the new driver session *after* throwing exception to the `retryAnalyzer` , i.e. re-initialising new driver session in the 2nd try (doesn't matter if this is re-initialised in the very first time of my @Test) this seems to be too late.

I don't know why retryAnalyzer behaves like this or what is the reason behind it, but this solution works for me.

This sample codes work for me:

```java
public class myTest {

  private WebDriver driver;

  //This codes in BeforeTest below will initiate a new chrome driver session 
  @BeforeTest
  public void initiate() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverpathchrome);
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("www.test.com");
    log.info("Chrome browser launched. Going to " + "www.test.com");
  }


  private boolean isBrowserOpen() {
    try {
      driver.getTitle();
      return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public boolean amISeeingLoginScreenNow() {
    if (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".login-box.smaller")).size() != 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  //This is the test methods
  @Test(retryAnalyzer = myTest.RetryAnalyzer.class)
  private void loginToTestURL() throws Exception {

    //This will check if the current browser session is still open. If not, then create a new driver session
    if (this.isBrowserOpen() == false) {
      Thread.sleep(3000);

      // Initiating new Browser 
      this.initiate();
    } else {
      driver.get("www.test.com");
    }


    this.method_will_not_throw_exception() {
      //some codes that will work OK
    }


    try {
      this.method_will_throw_exception() {
        //some codes that will throw exception
        this.amISeeingLoginScreenNow(); //In the 2nd try , at this stage, Selenium will get grumpy
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      //put exception in the log files then re-throw the exception
      //retryAnalyzer will get the exception and then start the test from the start of @Test
      driver.quit();

      Thread.sleep(1000);
      this.initiate(); //re-initialise the new driver session before throwing exception to the retryAnalyzer

      throw new AssertionError();
    }

  }
}
```